# grafana dashboards lost when kubernetes pods restart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana

I have installed Grafana on my kubernetes cluster via helm.my problem is whenever pods restart I lose my grafana dashboards.I really do not know what problem is.

---

How can I persistant my dashboards? any solution would be my appriciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount `/var/lib/grafana` in the pod to a PVC or NFS.

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
      name: grafana-pv

  volumes:
  - name: grafana-pv
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: grafana-pvc
```

For installation using Helm, overwrite the values:

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: should I Import volumeMounts and volumes into values.yaml file?where can I find them?@Lukman

Comment: volumeMounts and volumes if you directly modify the deployment. If you want to edit values.yaml, use the persistence.enabled: true

Comment: what will happen to dashboard if service goes down or delete ? Do They still exist?@lukman